# Columns order in document set welcome page view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-set

Is there a way to choose a specific order of the metadata columns that are displayed in the properties of the document set within "welcome page" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the metadata columns displayed on the welcome page depends on your settings via library settings>Document Set under content types>Document Set settings>Welcome Page Columns:

[image]